# Why does -ms-overflow-style exist?

Tags: css, scrollbar, overflow, internet-explorer-11

When comparing the `-ms-overflow-style` CSS property to `overflow`, I see little difference in terms of the use case, other than the auto-hide scrollbar feature.

macOS already has the feature to auto-hide the scrollbar. So it seems to me that delegating the hidden scrollbar implementation to the browser instead of the OS is kind of a headache.

What reasons might Microsoft have had to make this CSS property?

Sources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/CSS/-ms-overflow-style
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to enable scrollbar but want to have ability to scroll, you use `-ms-overflow-style` or `::-webkit-scrollbar` with width or height with 0. `-ms-overflow-style` is the equivalent to `::webkit-scrollbar` in case of visibility and ability to scroll.